# How to connect Ethernet via a Huawei Smart AXMT880s modem (with auto-detection)?

Tags: networking

It's been well over six months but I have the same router SmartAX MT880d with Ethernet, and the exact same problem : no internet, even though I can successfully reach the modem settings page by entering 192.168.1.1 in Firefox.

I'm a total beginner with Ubuntu. My internet works great in Windows but does not work in Ubuntu.

Sorry if I don't use the right (technical) terminology to explain my issue. English is not my mother tongue.

For 2 weeks, I've been doing reading on the web and forums and the ubuntuguide.org to name a few, but to no avail. Now I see no other solution but to ask for help.

My problem is that I can't find a way to put the right digits in the right place because I don't know what numbers I need to put in what files. E.g.: do I need to use DHCP? or a static IP address? No clue whatsoever. I'm concerned that I might put figures in the wrong spaces. For example, is the modem/router's IP exactly 192.168.1.1 for Huawei Smart AXMT880d modem? Is the subnet 255.255.255.0? Gateway 192.168.1.1?

I'm confused as I can also see a different IP starting with 155131***** (is it an account number?) on my contract with Huawei (a Chinese ISP).

- Apart from calling 911, what other numbers do I need to put in and where?
- How do I check that all the numbers have been entered correctly in every appropriate space before trying to connect the Internet?

---

Further development of the issue:

First as per the post below, I successfully disabled IPv6 from article called "Simple Way to Disable IPv6 in Windows Vista". Then I tried connecting to the Internet in Ubuntu, to no avail again.

Then I checked my settings in Ubuntu. I typed /etc/network/interfaces. There appears the loopback setting only, i.e.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I also checked `/etc/resolv.conf` but it's empty.

At this stage, the network manager still does not detect anything even after having disabled IPv6.

Then I tried Scaine's suggestion about pppoeconf coming from an article translated from Chinese. So I did the steps below and rebooted as the restart option (last step of the procedure below) has frozen for 2 minutes before i decided to reboot...(is that supposed to freeze at this stage??):

---

Basically, from the article (I have obviously not tested this!):

> ```
> sudo apt-get install pppoeconf
> ```
>
> To start the ADSL connection when
>   needed, in a terminal, `sudo pon
>   dsl-provider` To disconnect the ADSL
>   connection, you can enter in a
>   terminal, `sudo poff` If you need to
>   check the log, you can enter in a
>   terminal `plog`. Access to interface
>   information in a terminal type
>   `ifconfig ppp0`
>
> After using the pppoeconf if Network
>   Manager does not display hosted
>   solution:
>
> Enter the following command in a
>   terminal to configure a network
>   connection : `sudo gedit
>   /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf`
>   and change
>
> ```
> [ifupdown] managed = false
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> [ifupdown] managed = true
> ```
>
> Then in terminal run `sudo gedit
>   /etc/network/interfaces` and keep only
>   :
>
> ```
> auto lo
> iface lo inet loopback
> ```
>
> Delete dns settings `sudo mv
>   /etc/resolv.conf`
>   `/etc/resolv.conf_backup`
>
> Finally restart network-manager: `sudo
>   service network-manager restart`

---

After that, the settings remained the same. That is, in `/etc/network/interfaces`, still the loopback settings, and `/etc/resolv.conf` is still empty.

Then, I tried [Simon Bridge's advice about pppoeconf (in post #8)](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/how-to-install-ethernet-modem-huawei-smartax-mt880-638425/)

I tried that `pppoeconf` before registering on AskUbuntu.com and after reading and trying everything in this thread (until 16th March 2011).

My view on the topic is that by having tested many things different tips one after the other, I may have mixed settings in the end.

TO SUM UP NOW:

- IPv6 is disabled. In addition, in ipconfig /all in windows, I now noticed that DHCP is on for the Wireless LAN Adapter Wireless Network Connection, and Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection just shows the description of it: VIA VelocityFamily Gigabit Ethernet Adapter. That's it. The Ethernet is not "on" anymore. What should I do now??? Setting the IP address maybe???
- As a result, DHCP is on in Windows (for the wireless) but still does not auto-detect anything yet (same thing for DHCP as a matter of fact. For the wireless, no detection although i can see the different wireless networks)
- pppoeconf does not detect anything either after having done everything below.

Therefore, I think there's a setting which has not been set correctly somewhere but where? That remains a question...Thx anyway to you all. If you have any suggestion...
I'm grateful to you anyway.

---

Edit:

Hi Scaine, here are some interesting results from pppoeconf! I think I'm about to succeed....but one more barrier below. Could you please help guide me again? What do I have to do to turn on that Internet connection? when I enter sudo pon dsl-provider, nothing (I can see) happens...

```
joel@ubuntu:~$ sudo pppoeconf 
[sudo] password for joel:  
Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded. 
RP-PPPoE plugin version 3.8p compiled against pppd 2.4.5 
joel@ubuntu:~$ plog 
Mar 16 21:08:14 ubuntu pppd[1840]: Remote message: Authentication success,Welcome! 
Mar 16 21:08:14 ubuntu pppd[1840]: PAP authentication succeeded 
Mar 16 21:08:14 ubuntu pppd[1840]: peer from calling number 00:25:9E:F1:C1:9C authorized 
Mar 16 21:08:14 ubuntu pppd[1840]: Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP 
Mar 16 21:08:14 ubuntu pppd[1840]: local  IP address 27.190.153.195 
Mar 16 21:08:14 ubuntu pppd[1840]: remote IP address 27.190.152.1 
Mar 16 21:08:14 ubuntu pppd[1840]: primary   DNS address 222.222.202.202 
Mar 16 21:08:14 ubuntu pppd[1840]: secondary DNS address 222.222.222.222 
joel@ubuntu:~$ pon dsl-provider 
Error: only members of the 'dip' group can use this command. 
joel@ubuntu:~$ sudo pon dsl-provider 
Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded. 
RP-PPPoE plugin version 3.8p compiled against pppd 2.4.5
```

Comment: Have you tried using **[network-manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager)**, instead of configuring it manually?

Comment: The number you think might be a Huawei account number, is probably an account number, and I think you could safely delete it from this question.

Comment: It would also be typical for your subscriber subnet to be 255.255.255.0. A gateway address of 192.168.1.1 would also be very common.  Your Ubuntu system will likely need a 192.168.1.x address, where 'x' is a number between 2 and 254 (assuming your gateway is .1)  I wouldn't worry about getting everything correct before attempting to connect to the internet -- just try and if it fails, make changes and try again.   And Scaine's answer should get you the info you need.

Comment: Looks like you're asking here after this thread on linuxquestions didn't help you?  http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/how-to-install-ethernet-modem-huawei-smartax-mt880-638425/  I put this in for reference in case someone can figure out why this isn't working for you.

Comment: Perhaps try putting sudo in front of pppoeconf?  `sudo pppoeconf`?

Comment: There is that line though that is intriguing me:

ubuntu pppd[1840]: Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP

Comment: I'll keep you posted. I found some links on the web about that line above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding a separate answer here, since while my first answer is relevant generally, it looks like the SmartAX MT880d modem/router requires a different approach.  I found [this site](http://dqzx.neuq.edu.cn/bbs/viewthread.php?tid=890) which (with the help of Google Translate) outlines how to install ppoeconf and set up this modem under Ubuntu.

Basically, from the article (I have obviously **not** tested this!):

```
sudo apt-get install pppoeconf
```

Then run the command with `sudo pppoeconf`, putting your account details in, as prompted.

To start the ADSL connection when needed, in a terminal, `sudo pon dsl-provider`
To disconnect the ADSL connection, you can enter in a terminal, `sudo poff`
If you need to check the log, you can enter in a terminal `plog`.
Access to interface information in a terminal type, `ifconfig ppp0`

After using the `pppoeconf` if Network Manager does not display hosted solution:

Enter the following command in a terminal to configure a network connection:

```
gksu gedit /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf
```

And change

```
[ifupdown] managed = false
```

to:

```
[ifupdown] managed = true
```

Then in terminal run `gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces` and keep only:

```
auto lo iface lo inet loopback
```

Delete DNS settings: `sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf_backup`

Finally restart network-manager: `sudo service network-manager restart` (Or reboot!)

Answer (score 1):

If your PC works with this modem in Windows, it should be quite easy to copy those settings to Ubuntu.  In **Windows**, open a command window and type `ipconfig /all`.

[image: Windows command window]

In this screenshot above, you can see that DHCP is **not** enabled, so in this case, I'd have to copy the settings down, in particular, `IP Address`, `Subnet Mask`, `Default Gateway` and `DNS Servers`.

Then in Ubuntu, we need to replicate those settings in Network Manager.  So right click on the network manager applet, choose "Edit Connections", then edit your "Auto eth0" connection to match what you saw in Windows.

[image: Network Manager settings]

If DHCP *was* enabled, then Ubuntu should simply work, since that's its default setting.

Comment: Oh my god! You rock. I am going to use that tip today. I'll let you know soon.

Comment: I just checked my settings on Windows.  DHCP is turned off as per PPP Adapter Broadband Connection in ipconfig /all. It however shows DHCP turned on in the Ethernet Adapter Local Area Connection. As Ubuntu still doesn't auto-detect my Ethernet connection, what should I follow between setting DHCP in Ubuntu and setting the Ethernet connection in Ubuntu? To me, both are fine...but which one shall I set in the easiest way? Thanks again (I have made a great leap in my understanding of networks).

Comment: I don't think the PPP adapter is relevant.  If the ethernet adapter in Windows says DHCP, then Ubuntu should "just work".  Since it's not working, I would suspect that you might have some IPv6 issues (just guessing).  Try searching this site for "disable IPv6".  At work at the moment, so can't be more help until later today (about 8 hours).

Answer (score 1):

I'm excited. I got it working...
I knew I would do it...ahahahah

Thanks to everyone!

After having deactivated IPv6 in Windows following [this tutorial for Vista](http://www.home-network-help.com/disable-ipv6.html), Scaine helped a great deal when they led me to type `sudo pppoeconf`. Then I entered the username and password shown on my Internet contract and always said "yes" when prompted. I then proceeded to run the `plog` command as you can see above in my terminal with that error message:

```
Mar 16 21:08:14 ubuntu pppd[1840]: Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP
```

Looking for that error in Google, I ran into [this post on justlinux](http://www.justlinux.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-62893.html).

As suggested by that link, I entered:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/ppp/options
```

<sub>[editor's note - added the `-H` flag]</sub>

and just disabled an option:
I changed it from `noauth` to `#noauth`. That is I just deactivated this option by adding `#` before `noauth`. I saved, used the `plog` command again in the terminal again without `sudo`, and went straight online.

I hope this post helps somebody else as much as you have all helped me. So grateful to you (after three weeks of research) YYYYYaaaaaaaaaaaayaayyyyy!!!

Comment: Great news - I've never used `pppoeconf` before, so I'm glad it's worked out for you!  I have no idea if you need the `plog` command each time on boot, but if you do, search this site for "run command on start up" or something similar.  Good luck.

Comment: I've rebooted my machine to test whether I needed to manually use that plog command. And apparently, it lets me in every time without typing it in. So far so good. Fingers crossed. Cheers.